# WSO2 esb and as cluster togther

Tags: wso2

Has anyone successfully created AS and ESB cluster together?

I am trying to create test cluster with 1 ELB fronting 3 ESB nodes (1 mgt & 2 workers) and 3 AS nodes (1 mgt & 2 workers).

I followed 4.1.0 cluster creation guide  here http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+WSO2+Products and had ESB cluster working successfully.

However when I try to add AS cluster to LB, following instructions on above link it, whole thing fell-a-part. My suspicion is on proxyPort mapping for AS.

I was wondering if any one had successfully created cluster setup  as above and can share the over all steps.

Comment: What are the versions of AS, ESB, and ELB.?

Comment: AS 5.1.0, ESB 4.7.0 and ELB 2.0.3

Comment: It should work correctly. Did you change the port offset correctly avoiding any port conflicts. Also what is the error you are getting..?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue by adding new axis2 transports on ELB.

My set up as follows: ELB ports 8280 and 8243 going ESB clusters. ELB ports 80 and 443 going to AS cluster.

How ELB loadbalancer.conf works is not clear. Hope great people of WOS2 improve ELB  documentation.